# width: 100% making things go out of the div

Tags: css, html, textarea

I have a simple div in which I have 2 textarea. I set the textarea's width to `100%` but then it just go a little out of the div.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YE5MP/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="offer_a_help">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <br/>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.offer_a_help {
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100%/2 - 350px/2);
    left: calc(100%/2 - 250px/2);
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.offer_a_help textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Why is that happening and what's the simplest way to fix this?

Comment: Do you care about the width of the textarea or do you just want the overflow to be hidden?

Comment: A simple fix would be to lower the `width` to `97%` and add a `margin-left: 2` in `.offer_a_help textarea`. That also depends on the look you're going for, but it will give some small margins on the left and right making the textarea sit inside the background box.

Comment: What purpose is `calc()` serving here?

Comment: positioning it right in the center of the page

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Could you change your accepted answer to the answer of Daniel? It is the most valid answer and will most likely be more helpful than any other answer in this topic. Mishik answer is not good enough because it's hacky and you can't even use a padding. It's for future people finding this question. Ty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset padding and margin (I've set margin to -1 to accomodate outer div border):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YE5MP/2/)

```
.offer_a_help textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 3px -1px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I believe it may be an issue with the textarea having either a border or padding.  Both of those would be calculated with the 100% width and cause the width to be wider than the container.

You can add border-box to make the padding and border be calculated WITH the width instead of IN ADDITION to

Try adding:

```
.offer_a_help textarea {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: It works in the majority of the browsers in use:  http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing.

Comment: This is in my opinion a better answer than above.

Answer (score 1):

Change your css to this.

```
.offer_a_help textarea {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

You can also add padding to your `.offer_a_help class`

http://jsfiddle.net/YE5MP/5/